# upload file in selenium grid using c#

Tags: c#, selenium-grid

I had a question. I am trying to upload a file. It works fine with local webdriver. But when I try to upload it in RemoteWebDriver, it gives me the following error

> unknown error: path is not absolute

Would be great if you could help me figure out this issue.
This is the code snippet I have and it is in c# and I am using docker as selenium grid.

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "RegistryExcelFile", "RegistryFile.xlsx");
_driverFixture.Driver.FindElementById("filestyle-0").SendKeys(filepath);
```